# Saving R list of plotly charts in HTML

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, plotly

Its my first time posting on Stackoverflow. I am facing a problem in R right now. I have a LIST of plotly line charts and I am trying to save all of them in one HTML file but I am not able to. In addition I also want to save all charts in pdf too.

I have the dataset "DataGlobal" with three columns

structure(list(YQ = c(“2021Q1”,"2021Q2", "2021Q3", "2021Q4", "2022Q1", "2022Q2", "2022Q3", "2022Q4" ), series = structure(c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L),
.Label = “Outlook”, class = “factor”), value = c(176, 168, 172, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = “data.frame”)

| YQ | series | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021Q1 | Outlook | 176 |
| 2021Q2 | Outlook | 168 |
| 2021Q3 | Outlook | 172 |
| 2021Q4 | Outlook | 176 |
| 2022Q1 | Outlook | 177 |
| 2022Q2 | Outlook | 178 |
| 2022Q3 | Outlook | 179 |
| 2022Q4 | Outlook | 180 |

and here is the code and the error I am getting:

```
globalplots = list()
for (i in 1:42) {
    p <- ggplot(DataGlobal, aes(YQ, value, colour = series, group = series))+
        geom_line(aes(linetype = series)) + 
        ggtitle("Variable 1") + 
        scale_linetype_manual(values = "solid", labels = c("Outlook")) + 
        scale_colour_manual(values = "red", labels = c("Outlook")) +
        scale_shape_manual(values = 46, labels = c("Outlook")) + 
        xlab("Quarters") +
        ylab("Numbers") +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "#993333", size = 6, angle = 45), legend.background = element_rect(fill = NULL))
    p <- ggplotly(p)
    globalplots[[i]] <- p
    }
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(globalplots), "index.html") 

Error in shouldEval(list) : 
'options' must be a fully named list, or have no names (NULL)
```

where globalplots is a list of plotly charts.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610.

Your chances of getting an answer are greater if you include a sample of your data and a copy of the code you used, not just the error message.

Comment: Thank you so much for guiding me.

Comment: Please always post the actual code for your data instead of formated tables. If you don't have the code, and have only the object itself, you can paste the output of `dput(DataGlobal)` or, if it is too big, `dput(your_subset_of_the_data)`

Comment: I would take a look at r-markdown.  You should be able to create a document with the plots of interest and then knit into html.